# bash script : how to update database table using postgres psql and UPDATE statement

Tags: bash, postgresql, sql-update, psql

How to assign a parameter/argument in postgres psql UPDATE command. I tried with the following command.

```
c="openssl rand -base64 6"
ab=eval $c
psql -d db_name -c "UPDATE table_name SET password = '$ab' WHERE name = 'cde'"
```

The above command updates the table 'table_name' in the colum 'password' as ' ' (quotes with empty string)instead of updating the value of '$ab'. The '$ab' is a string.

Could anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way it works:

```
c="openssl rand -base64 6"
ab=`$c`
psql -d db_name -c "UPDATE table_name SET password = '$ab' WHERE name = 'cde'"
```

Comment: Why don't you just write `ab=$( openssl rand -base64 6 )` to start with?